# Converting to one line AppleScript

Tags: applescript, line, applescript-objc

I have a series of AppleScript commands I need to implement into a single line of AppleScript. The code is below.

```
delay 2
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "foo"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do they need to be one-liners? Also: could you say which application is receiving the "foo" and "return"? This would make it easier to test your script. Beyond that, I´m assuming the second and third line can be joined to `tell app "System Events" to keystroke {"foo",return}`.

Comment: It needs to be one line because I am going to implement this AppleScript into a Cocoa application.

Comment: Couldn´t you handle the delay in Cocoa then?

Comment: I also do not see why that needs to be a single line. You can either use an escaped line break inside an NSString literal `@"foo\nbar"`. You could also use a literal line break in the NSString literal. Or if it is not a literal, you should still be able to manage to add a suitable line break character as a part of your string building.

Comment: @Asmus @Chris Johnsen Good point, I think I will handle the delay in Cocoa.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can combine the two *keystroke* commands into a single one by concatenating your strings together:

```
tell app "System Events" to keystroke "foo" & return
```

But that still leaves you with one command and a statement (*delay* and *tell … to …*).

Effectively, AppleScript’s statement separator is a line break. In modern AppleScript the line breaks can be either CR, LF, or CRLF (respectively: old-Mac-, Unix-, or DOS-style). There is no convenient way write a multi-statement line (like `foo; bar; baz;` in C, Perl, Ruby, et cetera).

For your specific request, you can combine the two in a really ugly way by using *delay* as a part of an expression.

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "" & (delay 2) & "foo" & return
```

This is ugly because *delay* technically returns no value, but we are able to concatenate it with an empty string without causing an error.

The problem is that such a construction is not very “general purpose”. You may not always be able to turn any command into an expression in the same way (and you can not use statements like *tell* as a part of an expression<sup>1</sup>). For a bit more brevity (and obfuscation), you can write the last bit as `"foo" & return & (delay 2)`. It still runs in the same order (*delay* first) because each part of the concatenation expression must be evaluated before it can be built into a single value for the *keystroke* command.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Short of putting them in a string given to *run script* that is. Even then, some statements (loops, try/catch, etc.) are always multi-line; though you can get around that by using escaped line breaks or concatenation and one of the line break constants (as follows).</sub>

You could use *run script* with a string argument and use the backslash<sup>2</sup> escapes to represent the line breaks.

```
run script "delay 0.1\ntell app \"System Events\" to keystroke \"foo\" & return"
```

*AppleScript Editor* may translate the escape notation into a literal unless you have “Escape tabs and line break in string” enabled in its Editing preferences (available in 10.5 and later). You could always use the *return* constant and concatenation instead of the in-string-literal/escape-notation.

```
run script "delay 0.1" & return & "tell app \"System Events\" to keystroke \"foo\" & return"
```

<sub><sup>2</sup> If you are going to represent such strings inside an Objective C string literal (as one of your comments might imply), then you will have to escape the backslashes and double quotes for Objective C, also (…`& \"tell app \\\"System`…).</sub>

Or, if you are ultimately trying to run the code with *osascript*, then you can use the fact that each instance of `-e` will become a separate line to put it all on a single shell command line.

```
osascript -e 'delay 2' -e 'tell app "System Events" to keystroke "foo" & return'
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `osascript -e 'line1' -e 'line2' …`

The manpage for `osascript` suggests to use several `-e` to build up a multi-line script:

> `-e statement` 
> Enter one line of a script.  If -e is given, osascript will not look for a filename in the argument list.
> **Multiple -e options may be given to build up a multi-line script.**
> Because most scripts use characters
> that are special to many shell programs (for example, AppleScript uses single and double quote marks, “(”,
> “)”, and “*”), the statement will have to be correctly quoted and escaped to get it past the shell intact.

Answer already given by Chris Johnsen, but is contained in a longer answer and therefore can be overlooked.